# how do I create underlined text with ::after and ::before pseudo elements?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create an underlined title with the after pseudo element, but a problem occurs where the element has a large width.

Making the underline bigger than the text, which I wanted to know how do I make the element the size of the text so it doesn't have to fix a size.

```css
 * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
 }

 .c-title {
   position: relative;
   
   text-transform: uppercase;

   font-size: 1.2em;
 }

 .c-title::after {
   content: "";
   width: 100%;
   height: .2em;
   
   background-color: var(--c-title-underline-color);
   
   position: absolute;
   bottom: -2px;
   left: 0;
 }
```

```html
<h1 class="c-title">text...</h1>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your color variable is not included in the CSS code. so use `background` instead of `background-color`. that's it.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
   }
  
   .c-title {
     position: relative;
     
     text-transform: uppercase;
  
     font-size: 1.2em;
     width: fit-content;
   }
  
   .c-title::after {
     content: "";
     width: 100%;
     height: .2em;
     
     /* background-color: var(--c-title-underline-color); */
     background: red;
     
     position: absolute;
     bottom: -2px;
     left: 0;
     
   }
```

```html
<h1 class="c-title">text...</h1>
```

Comment: in the original code it is defined correctly in root, I did not define it in the question because it is irrelevant. Thank you anyway.

Comment: it's absolutely relative because you want to show it as an underline for the text. anyway I just used background and it worked. isn't this what you want?

Comment: yes, it worked correctly with what you recommended and with my changes, thanks.